# Xamarin.Forms How to create Bottom Sheets using custom renderer?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tried invoking some nuget packages but nothing worked!My view also has a map,want the bottom sheets to have some options for map interactivity!

Comment: what is "bottom sheets"?  Do you have some sort of example or image of what you're trying to do?

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2016/07/android-bottom-sheet-example/

Comment: Do you mean the action sheet in iOS? Like this: [Guiding Users Through Tasks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/pop-ups/#Guiding_Users_Through_Tasks)

Comment: I don't want action sheets, because it pops in the middle and disables the background, I want a menu to pop from the bottom and resize back down based on user swipe movement.